# Display user information with a username after the /user/

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

On Facebook you can go to "https://facebook.com/SomeUsernameHere" and it will display that users profile, I have tried searching and cannot find how to do this, can someone help?

Comment: Like this? https://www.facebook.com/username/about

Comment: Err.... how to do what? Meaning, if user id is 87772130987123 and you want to show JohnDoe as the URL? If so, that's called a mod rewrite.

Comment: Yes like that, is it possible to do that with PHP?

Comment: *Sure is possible!* Here http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ and Google "mod rewrite php" *for more results.*

Comment: You're welcome. *Enjoy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible in php but you will have to use a framework.
Facebook too is developed using some framework i guess

I will take a eg. of codeigniter - a framework of php to show you how this can be can de done.

Mycontroller.php

```
<?php
    class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller
    {
      public function index($username) 
      {
        //some logic
      }
    }
?>
```

here you can make your domain to direct  to **Mycontroller class -> index function.**

url will be like:
**http://something.com** -> this will redicect you to  **Mycontroller class -> index function**.
And as your index function requires a parameter you can send a parameter from url as you needed.

**http://something.com/someusername**

by using this parameter you can do further process such as getting details of that username from database and displaying it and so on.....

Hope this helps.